# Why can't I join FileReader and System.out.println in one line?

Tags: java, filereader

Can some one help me, why can't I join FileReader and System.out.println in one line.

```java
    File cf = new File("D:\\jv\\test.txt");
        FileReader cfr = new FileReader(cf);
        char[] cc = new char[4096];
        cfr.read(cc);             // join line 1
        System.out.println(cc);   // join line 2
//        Jointing line 1 and 2 gives the file lenth only, not the content.
//        System.out.println(cfr.read(cc));*
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, your Code is wrong. You have to remember how many characters have been read. `int charsRead = cfr.read(cc);` and then `System.out.println(new String(cc, 0, charsRead));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing what `cfr.read` does vs. what `System.out.println` does.

- `FileReader` will provide you an API to perform file reading tasks.
- `System.out.println` will allow you to "print a line" to the "System.out" channel (the console).

`System.out.println(cfr.read(cc));` This line will not print out a string as method `cfr.read()` does not return a String. It returns an `int` see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-